# Conditional queries WP_query based on term

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements

Basically would like to show first posts with term = arts, if doesn't exist then display posts with term = guides.

These are my two arguments, i've been trying to use has_term outside loop but not working.

```
<?php

if ( has_term( 'arts', 'postkicker' )){

$args=array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'taxonomy'  => 'postkicker',
    'term'      => 'arts',
    'orderby'   => 'date',
    'order'     => 'DESC'
);

} else {

$args=array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'taxonomy'  => 'postkicker',
    'term'      => 'guides',
    'orderby'    => 'date',
    'order'      => 'DESC'
);

} 

$my_query = new WP_Query($args);

if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
    the_title( sprintf( "<h1><a href='%s' rel='bookmark'>", esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), "</a></h1>" ); 

    endwhile;wp_reset_postdata();endif; 
?>
```

Any suggestions? Do I need to move my has_term within the loop?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close -> but you should instead try to

```
<?php

$first_args=array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'taxonomy'  => 'postkicker',
    'term'      => 'arts',
    'orderby'   => 'date',
    'order'     => 'DESC'
);


$second_args=array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'taxonomy'  => 'postkicker',
    'term'      => 'guides',
    'orderby'    => 'date',
    'order'      => 'DESC'
);

$first_query = new WP_Query($first_args);

if ($first_query->have_posts() ) {
     // Do your HTML
 }
 else {
 $second_query = new WP_Query($second_args);
 if ($second_query->have_posts() ){
    // Do your HTML
    }     
 }
```

that should be enough to get you started :)